Filtering array based on property of another array in mongodb aggregation
So let's say i have this document
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "array": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "nestedArray": [
          {
            "value": "661564ce168c8115295a8f25"
          }
        ],
        "nestedArray2": [
          {
            "valueToFilter": ObjectId("661564ce168c8115295a8f25")
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "nestedArray": [
          {
            "value": "661564ce168c8115295a8f27"
          },
                    {
            "value": "661564ce168c8115295a8f28"
          }
        ],
        "nestedArray2": [
          {
            "valueToFilter": ObjectId("661564ce168c8115295a8f29")
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

What i need is to fetch _id and whole array properties if AT LEAST one item inside nestedArray2.valueToFilter does not exist inside nestedArray.value
So in this example, the aggregation would return this document because nestedArray2.valueToFilter: v3 does not exist in at least one nestedArray.value
If all valueToFilter exists in at least one nestedArray.value, then do not fetch this document

Okay, and what have you tried so far? Welcome to StackOverflow. Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Please take the tour and read How do I ask a good question?.

Generally, I don't recommend schema with highly nested arrays. Nevertheless, in your scenario, you can first perform an element-wise operation on array to compute the $setIntersection of nestedArray and $nestedArray2. Then, use  $anyElementTrue to filter the result.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "array": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$array",
          "as": "a",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$a",
              {
                nestedArray: {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": "$$a.nestedArray",
                    "as": "na",
                    "in": {
                      "value": {
                        "$toObjectId": "$$na.value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "test": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$array",
          "as": "arr",
          "in": {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$$arr.nestedArray.value",
              "$$arr.nestedArray2.valueToFilter"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$anyElementTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$test",
            "as": "t",
            "in": {
              $eq: [
                [],
                "$$t"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "test"
  }
])

Mongo Playground

The above playground demonstrates the concepts. You can use the below version for concise syntax.
Mongo Playground

One shortcut I like using for multiple equality tests against empty/non-empty is max/min. In this case simplifying the $match to: { $expr: { $eq: [{ $min: "$test" }, []] } } Mongo playground with better data

@aneroid That is some clever hacks! Thanks for teaching me that :)

@aneroid thanks for the answers. The problem is that i just saw the db structure and it happens that nestedArray.value is a string and nestedArray2.valueToFilter is an ObjectId, which causes the intersection to fail. is there any way to fix it? i tried using $toObjectId/$toString but apparently it is not allowed inside the $setIntersection

@matthew can you [edit] the question to include the sample document?

@ray updated as requested

@aneroid sorry for the confusion, i have fixed the ObjectIds, thanks for the suggestions.

@matthew updated the answer to adjust to the changes. Basically, I am sanitizing the field with $toObjectId before the pipeline. However, you can see the code is getting complicated with a lot of $mergeObjects due to your highly nested structure. You are reminded of the advantages of refactoring the array entries into individual documents in previous comments
